# Newly created item show only after refresh in mat table

Tags: angular, service, angular-material-table, rerender

I'm new to Angular and I've been struggling a bit with this:

I have an Angular Material table whose dataSource, as you can see in the code below, is a variable named "students". This variable contains the students data provided by a students service. If I update or delete a student from the table, it will automatically re-render and show the updated data correctly. My problem lies in that when I create a new student the table won't re-render and it'll only show the newly created student after refreshing. How can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

This is what I've got so far...

student.service.ts:

```
export class StudentService {

  public element: Student;

  private studentsSubject: BehaviorSubject<Student[]> = new BehaviorSubject<Student[]>([]);
  public students$: Observable<Student[]> = this.studentsSubject.asObservable();

  private modeSubject: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject('Crear');
  public mode$: Observable<string> = this.modeSubject.asObservable();
  
  constructor(
    private httpClient: HttpClient
  ) {
    this.getStudentsFromAPI().subscribe(students => {
      this.studentsSubject.next(students);
    })
  }

  getStudentsFromAPI(): Observable<Student[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Student[]>('https://63cc20169b72d2a88e0893c6.mockapi.io/alumnos');
  }

  createStudent(student: Student): void {
    let newId = this.studentsSubject.getValue().length + 1;
    let newStudent = {...student, id: newId, commissionId: null};
    let newList = this.studentsSubject.getValue();
    
    this.httpClient.post('https://63cc20169b72d2a88e0893c6.mockapi.io/alumnos', newStudent).subscribe(_ => {
      newList.push(newStudent);
      this.studentsSubject.next(newList);
    })
  }

  updateStudent(student: Student): void {
    let updatedStudent = this.studentsSubject.getValue().find(stu => stu.id === student.id);
    updatedStudent = {...updatedStudent, ...student}
    
    this.httpClient.put(`https://63cc20169b72d2a88e0893c6.mockapi.io/alumnos/${student.id}`, updatedStudent).subscribe(_ => {
      let newList = this.studentsSubject.getValue().map(stu => stu.id === updatedStudent!.id ? updatedStudent! : stu);
      this.studentsSubject.next(newList)
    })
  }

  deleteStudent(student: Student): void {
    this.httpClient.delete(`https://63cc20169b72d2a88e0893c6.mockapi.io/alumnos/${student.id}`).subscribe(_ => {
      let newList = this.studentsSubject.getValue().filter(stu => stu.id !== student.id);
      this.studentsSubject.next(newList);
    })
  }

  setModeObservable(mode: string): void {
    this.modeSubject.next(mode);
  }

  setElement(element: Student): void {
    this.element = element;
  }
}
```

students-list.component.ts:

```
export class StudentsListComponent implements OnDestroy {

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['ID', 'Alumno', 'Email', 'Editar', 'Eliminar'];

  studentsSubscription: Subscription;
  coursesSubscription: Subscription;
  modeSubscription: Subscription;

  public students: Student[];
  public courses: CourseInterface[];
  public mode: string;

  constructor(private studentService: StudentService, private courseService: CoursesService) { 
    this.studentsSubscription = this.studentService.students$.subscribe(students => {
      this.students = students;
    } );

    this.coursesSubscription = this.courseService.courses$.subscribe(courses => this.courses = courses);

    this.modeSubscription = this.studentService.mode$.subscribe(mode => {
      this.mode = mode
    })
  }


  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.studentsSubscription.unsubscribe();
    this.coursesSubscription.unsubscribe();
    this.modeSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  delete(student: Student): void {
    this.studentService.deleteStudent(student);
  }

  setMode(mode: string, element: Student) {
    this.studentService.setElement(element)
    this.studentService.setModeObservable(mode);
  }

}
```

EDIT

As requested, here's my HTML:

```
<div class=" my-5" >
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="students" class="mat-elevation-z8">
      <ng-container matColumnDef="ID">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ID </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.id}} </td>
      </ng-container>
    
      <ng-container matColumnDef="Alumno">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Nombre y Apellido </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element | studentsNamesPipe}}</td>
      </ng-container>
    
      <ng-container matColumnDef="Email">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Email </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.email}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="Editar">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
          <button mat-icon-button color="primary" (click)="setMode('Editar', element)">
            <mat-icon >edit</mat-icon>
          </button>
        </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="Eliminar">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
          <button mat-icon-button color="warn" (click)="delete(element)">
            <mat-icon >delete</mat-icon>
          </button>
        </td>
      </ng-container>
    
      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

EDIT 2:

StackBlitz link with all this code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jcsebj?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Please share your html.

Comment: Done! Sorry I didn't share it in the first place.

Comment: I could not find any errors in your code. If you can create a StackBlitz sample, I might be able to help more.

Comment: Sure, here it is: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jcsebj?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add or delete an element in `mat-table`, you have to create a new array instance to re-render the table.

In `createStudent`, `newList` is derived from `this.studentsSubject.getValue()`, which uses an existing array instance. So your table does not be rendered.

In `deleteStudent`, you are creating new array instance for `newList`. So your table is re-rendered.

One solution is to create a new array instance for `newList`.

```
  createStudent(student: Student): void {
           :
    let newList = [...this.studentsSubject.getValue()];
           :
  }
```

Comment: It works! It was such a stupid issue but I just couldn't figure it out and it bugged me a lot. Thank you so much for taking the time to read my code multiple times and help me.

Answer (score 0):

try changinging the intialization of students:

```
students= new MatTableDataSource<Student>();
```

And also in your Constructor:

```
this.studentsSubscription = this.studentService.students$.subscribe(students => {
      this.students.data = students;
    } );
```